# Issue with async library for Google Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, asynchronous, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I am using the library https://github.com/spotify/async-datastore-client for async google datastore operations. When I run the following code it always output "Failure". I am testing this against my local development database. I am new to Google datastore so I am not sure what exactly is wrong although I have a gut feeling something is wrong with the datastore config (e.g do I need credentials, some other missing params?). I have not signed up for any Google services yet. I would just like to insert something into my local database and have it succeed using this library.

```
import com.spotify.asyncdatastoreclient.DatastoreConfig;
import com.spotify.asyncdatastoreclient.Datastore;
import com.spotify.asyncdatastoreclient.QueryBuilder;
import com.spotify.asyncdatastoreclient.Insert;
import com.spotify.asyncdatastoreclient.MutationResult;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;



public class Main{

    public void initDB() throws Exception {

     final DatastoreConfig config = DatastoreConfig.builder()
    .requestTimeout(1000)
    .requestRetry(3)
    .host("http://localhost:8080")
    .dataset("async-test")
    //.credential(DatastoreHelper.getServiceAccountCredential(null, null))
    .build();

final Datastore datastore = Datastore.create(config);

final Insert insert = QueryBuilder.insert("employee", 1234567L)
    .value("fullname", "Fred Blinge")
    .value("age", 40);

// for asynchronous call...
final ListenableFuture<MutationResult> resultAsync = datastore.executeAsync(insert);

      Futures.addCallback(resultAsync, new FutureCallback<MutationResult>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(final MutationResult result) {
          System.out.println("Success");
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(final Throwable throwable) {
          System.out.println("Failure");   
      }
    });

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to set credentials, host and dataset. can you try w/o this?

Comment: I tried to comment out all 3 of those methods, but it did not work.

Comment: can you also show error message and stackrace?